# How to run HBase in distributed mode on windows without cygwin?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

- I have configured HBase and integrated with HDFS on windows successfully. I using HBase version 0.98.6.1-hadoop2 and Hadoop version 2.5.1
- Followed HBase [quick start](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html) tutorial.
- If i run HBase normally (without **hbase.cluster.distributed property**) then it works fine. Otherwise it shows **This is not implemented yet. Stay tuned.**
- How do i start HBase in cluster distributed mode on windows without cygwin?

Comment: I added 'without cygwin' to title. If some thing works on cygwin and not on windows that me be linked to different location for $HOME (and hence ssh keys etc). I do  not know hadoop...just a speculation.

Comment: no cygwin? then "use the force, Luke" - virtualbox, vmware, parallels, etc...

Comment: @ursa i don't want unix environment. i want to implement in windows without any third party software.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can do in these ways

1) Use cygwin (not in your requirements).

2) Use VMWare or VirtualBox

3) Use Microsoft HDInsights (Suitable for you)

Before Starting Hbase make sure Hadoop is in distributed mode and is working only then your HBase will work in distributed mode else it will run in local mode.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay Tiwari. But Its not my requirement as you said. I could run if i use VM or cygwin. But HBase runs in stand-alone mode in windows without cygwin or any other tool for unix environment. As the same way i want to run in distributed mode.